# Remove all <br> just before closing </p>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I would like to remove any `<br>` tag which comes up just before a closing `</p>` tag.

For example this is ok :

```
<p>Bla bla bla <br>
bla bla
</p>
```

But this is **NOT** ok :

```
<p>Bla bla bla <br>
</p>
```

In other words, every time I have :

```
<br> + white space or tab or new line or whatever providing no content + </p>
```

Then, I want to remove that `<br>`.

How would this be achieved with javascript Regex ? (or any other javascript way)

Comment: I personaly don't think this is similar ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

Iterate through each `p`,
get its html (not text, in order to get the `<br>` element),
replace the `<br>` with empty string using regex (one that matches `<br>` just before the `</p>`),
replace the original with the updated html.

```
$('p').each(function(){
    var p = $(this);

    p.html(p.html().replace(/(<br)\s?\/?>\s?$/g,''));    

});
```

[REGEX](http://www.regexr.com/3ac64):
`/(<br)\s?\/?>\s?$/g` matches: `<br>, <br/>, <br />, <br >`

Comment: Are you sure this would remove only the `<br>` which is just before the closing `</p>` ?

Comment: Yes.. check this sample : http://jsfiddle.net/a4rnh6dw/. You may view the updated html via firebug/inspector

Comment: Thank you so much, after I ran some tests, it worked really good !

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like below. If the `br` is the last child remove it, else of the last child is empty then remove it

```js
$('p').find('br:last').filter(function () {
  return !this.nextSibling || (this.nextSibling.nodeType == 3 && !this.nextSibling.nextSibling && !this.nextSibling.nodeValue.trim())
}).remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Bla bla bla
  <br/>bla bla
</p>

<p>Bla bla bla
  <br></p>

<p>Bla bla bla
  <br>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The regexp would look like so:

```
/<br>\s*<\/p>/g
```

Meaning first a `"<br>"` + Any white space or newline + `"</p>"`

Then we use `str.match()`. And to remove the `<br>` we replace it with an empty string. Notice that `test1` didn't work while `test2` did:

```js
var test1 = "<p>Bla bla bla <br> \
bla bla \
</p>";

var test2 = "<p>Bla bla bla <br> \
</p>";

if(test1.match(/<br>\s*<\/p>/g))
    test1 = test1.replace("<br>","");

if(test2.match(/<br>\s*<\/p>/g))
    test2 = test2.replace("<br>","");

alert(test1); // <br> still there
alert(test2);// <br> is gone
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It looks like it works great. I chose the other answer because it happened to be closer to the way I wanted to implement it. Thank you again.